# Case keyword and setting variable in makefile

Tags: makefile

What do the following three lines do in a Makefile?

```
1. SRCS:c=o
2. case "$*" in
3. support)

 OBJS=$(SRCS:c=o)
 %.o: %.c
         case "$*" in \
             support) $(CC) $(CCOPT) -c $(OPTS) $*.c ;; \
             *) $(PCC) $(PCCOPT) -c $(OPTS) $*.c ;; \
             esac
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

`OBJS=$(SRCS:c=o)` is a [Substitution Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs):

> When we say “at the end of a word”, we mean that a must appear either followed by whitespace or at the end of the value in order to be replaced; other occurrences of a in the value are unaltered. For example:
>
> ```
> foo := a.o b.o c.o
> bar := $(foo:.o=.c)
> ```
>
> sets ‘bar’ to ‘a.c b.c c.c’. See Setting Variables.
>
> ...

This bit:

```
     case "$*" in \
         support) $(CC) $(CCOPT) -c $(OPTS) $*.c ;; \
         *) $(PCC) $(PCCOPT) -c $(OPTS) $*.c ;; \
         esac
```

is the recipe of the `%.o: %.c` target and is a shell script.

See `case` in the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-case) and in the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05).

The `support)` and `*)` bits are part of the `case` statement (as is `esac`).